# File Searcher: how to work with JFrame while main Thread Execute?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

This is my first post, so if something wrong, I'll try to fix it.
Test task I am dealing with is to make file searcher with ability to navigate text, etc. I finished this part except one thing: application needs to allow user work with it while it is searching files in directories.

I've read a lot about multithreading, but still can't get answer how to do this... This is a code which executes when user presses "Choose folder" in my JFrame("GUI" class):

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) jTree1.getModel();
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot();
    int j = jTree1.getRowCount() - 1;
    final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString() + " files", jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString());
    fc.setFileFilter(filter);
    fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    fc.setDialogTitle("Choose a folder to fing ." + jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString() + " files");
    jLabel4.setText("Searching files in folder, please wait");
    if (fc.showOpenDialog(jButton3) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        root.setUserObject("Your root");
        jTextArea1.setText("");
        jTextField1.setText("");
        if (jTree1.getRowCount() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
                model.removeNodeFromParent((MutableTreeNode) model.getChild(root, 0));
            }
        }
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        File f2 = new File(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
        String name2 = "." + jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        //FilenameFilter filter1 = (File dir, String name1) -> name1.endsWith(name2);
        ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
        new NewТhread();
        listf(f2, files, name2);
        root.setUserObject(f2);
        model.nodeChanged(root);
        for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(files.get(i).getAbsolutePath().replace(f2.toString(), ""));
            root.add(child);
            model.reload();
            jLabel4.setText("Done! Now type text to search and press \"Search files\"");
        }
        System.out.println("Time used for getting files: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000 + "sec");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Directory opened:" + fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("Main thread finished");
    } else if (fc.showOpenDialog(jButton3) == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
        jLabel4.setText("Please, choose folder and extension to find files");
    }
}
```

Listf is a method to check all subdirectories too:

```
    public ArrayList<File> listf(File directory, ArrayList<File> files, String extension) {
    File[] flist = directory.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < flist.length; i++) {
        if (flist[i].isFile() && flist[i].getName().endsWith(extension) == true) {
            files.add(flist[i]);
        } else if (flist[i].isDirectory()) {
            listf(flist[i], files, extension);
        }
    }
    return files;
}
```

NewThread is a class that I still can't get in. For now it looks like this:

```
class NewТhread extends Thread {

NewТhread() {
    super("Demo");
    start();
}

public synchronized void run() {
    try {
        for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.println(i);
            GUI gui = new GUI();
            gui.setVisible(true);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException е) {
        System.out.println("Interrupted");
    }
}
```

After 3-2-1 count it should open new GUI object (JFrame) that should allow to make all the actions. Now all the elements of object GUI gui are frozen while main thread executes (and become unfrozen only when search finishes).
Could you help, please?

Comment: Cann't understand what you want to achive. You should try to read about [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). Probably this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply start a thread by putting only the code, which does not require user's interaction, inside the thread's run method as shown below:

```
new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {
        // code which does not require user's interaction
    }
}.start();
```

In your case the code to be placed in run method, will be the code written in "jButton1ActionPerformed" action listener. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone. I've found decision with ExecutorService, it allows to not freeze project while data is loading.